# How to find out all the matrices that satisfy $A^TMA=M$, where $M\in SO(n,1)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I want to solve the following matrix equation:

$$
A^TMA=M,
where M=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& \cdots & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 &\cdots &0 &0\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there a closed-form expression for A, or for several matrices that A can be decomposed to?

Moreover, if we not assume A is a square matrix, but a matrix of $m\times n$, then how about
$$
A^TM_mA=M_n
$$

Comment: Are you looking for $A$ in $SO_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an infinite class of solutions.

First, let $B$ be any $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix such that $B^TB=I_{n-1}$ and set
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1,1} & b_{1,2}& \cdots & b_{1,n-1} & 0\\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} &\cdots &b_{2,n-1} &0\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
b_{n-1,1} &  & \cdots & b_{n-1,n-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$

It is easy to see that $AM=MA$. Moreover, $A^TA=I_n$ since $B^TB=I_{n-1}$.

It follows that
$$
A^TMA= A^TAM=I_nM=M \,.
$$
Since there are infinitely many choices of $B$, this describes infinitely many solutions.

Morever $\det(A)=-\det(B)$ tells you that picking $B \in O_{n-1}\backslash SO_{n-1}$ gives you $A \in SO_n$.

Comment: The answer is clear and easy to follow! Thanks for your prompt response. It's of great help to me!